# Play framework 2.4 GlobalSettings. no interface expected here

Tags: java, spring, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.4

I am new to the Play framework and Java in general. What is wrong with this Global.java file? I get the error `no interface expected here` on the line `public class Global extends GlobalSettings {`

```
import play.*;
import play.libs.*;
import com.avaje.ebean.Ebean;
import models.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import play.api.Application;
import play.api.GlobalSettings;


public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    @Override
    public void onStart(Application app) {
        if(User.find.findRowCount() == 0){
            Ebean.save((List) Yaml.load("initial-data.yml"));
        }
        //Start Spring WS framework
        applicationContext.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(Application app) {
    applicationContext.stop();
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a simple SOAP web service within Play Java using the Spring framework. Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the play.api.GlobalSettings import. Do the same for play.api.Application. These...

```
import play.api.Application;
import play.api.GlobalSettings;
```

It looks like your project has defaulted to a Scala project rather than a Java one, I think. You should be using the play.GlobalSettings and play.Application objects for a Java Play application, covered by your current play.* import.

Comment: That fixed it. I had another error in the code, the line should obviously read `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml")`

Comment: @ManoDestra even `import play.*` didn't resolve GlobalSettings class for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SwapnilB. Without seeing your code, it's difficult to say. Perhaps raise a specific question about your issue?